# QMI SDK start data session

Tags: c, mobile

I am using QMI SDK to start data session for the Sierra Wireless card MC7354 and Telus Sim Card. For now I can detect the device and the sim card like getting device info and IMSI number; however, I got some trouble with starting the data session. I follow the instructions in QMI SDK Documents and do the following code:

```
//set the default profile
ULONG rc3 = SetDefaultProfile(0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
fprintf(stderr, "SetProfile - Return Code: %lu\n", rc3);

//start the session
ULONG technology = 1;
ULONG profile_idx = 1;
struct ssdatasession_params session;
session.action = 1;
session.pTechnology = &technology;
session.pProfileId3GPP = &profile_idx;
session.pProfileId3GPP2 = NULL;
session.ipfamily = 4;
ULONG rc4 = SLQSStartStopDataSession(&session);
fprintf(stderr, "Start Session - Return Code: %lu\n",rc4);
```

SetDefaultProfile is working fine because it returns me the success code, but for the SLQSStartStopDataSession method, it always gives me the return code "1026", which means

```
Requested operation would have no effect
```

Does anyone know where I make mistakes and how should I modify the code? What does this return code mean?

Comment: Are you possibly already connected? Maybe the modem automatically connects after attach per profile setting.

Answer (score 0):

A "No Effect" error in WDS Start Network (the underlying command sent when you use SLQSStartStopDataSession()) actually means that the device is already connected. You likely have configured an automatic connection setup in the modem.